# How to set the camera size on a preview view layer

Tags: ios, swift

I use below code to show a camera on a iPhone device. The camera can be displayed the UI and I am able to take picture. However, the camera is only shown in the middle of the previewLayer. How to make the camera to fill up all space on a AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer? I have tried to use AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill gravity but it will make the image out of shape.

```
self.session = AVCaptureSession()
        do {
            let device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
            try self.videoInput = AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
        } catch {

        }
        if ((self.session?.canSetSessionPreset(AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh)) != nil){
            self.session?.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh
        }
        self.stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()

        self.stillImageOutput?.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey:AVVideoCodecJPEG]
        if self.session!.canAddInput(self.videoInput){
            self.session?.addInput(self.videoInput)
        }
        if self.session!.canAddOutput(self.stillImageOutput){
            self.session?.addOutput(self.stillImageOutput)
        }

self.previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self.session)
        //self.backView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.width,self.view.bounds.width)
        let viewLayer:CALayer = self.backView.layer
        viewLayer.masksToBounds = true
        let bounds:CGRect = viewLayer.bounds
        self.previewLayer?.frame = bounds
        self.previewLayer?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        self.previewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect//AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect
        self.backView.layer.addSublayer(self.previewLayer!)
```

Below is the screenshot of the camera.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I'm doing this:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    videoPreviewLayer?.frame = previewView.layer.bounds
}
```

You can get wrong bounds if you do this in viewDidLoad().

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this

```
self.previewLayer?.frame = self.view.bounds //Or whatever size you want the previewLayer to fit.
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
 mainImagePicker.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 150)
```